# Embed Unity3D and load multiple games from a single app

Tags: unity

Is is possible to export an entire unity3d project/game as an AssetBundle and load it on iOS/Android/Windows on an app that doesn't know anything about such game beforehand? What I have in mind is something like the web plugin does - it loads a series of .unity3d files over http, and render inline in the browser window.

Is it even possible to do something closer for iOS/Android?

I have read a lot of docs so far, but still can't be sure:

- http://floored.com/blog/2013/integrating-unity3d-within-ios-native-application.html
- http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html
- http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html

The code from the post at http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/112703-Override-Unity-Data-folder-path?p=749108&viewfull=1#post749108 works for Android, but how about iOS and other platforms?

Comment: There may be platform restrictions on dynamic content for ios?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically speaking, you could achieve something along those lines using [AssetBundles](http://docs.unity3d.com/430/Documentation/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html), your "main game" would simply be a container loading asset bundles from your favorite CDN, and you would write new "games" on different scenes.

Each scene could be a game on it's own, stored in an asset bundle - and the main game scene simply switches between scenes/games.

This topic on the Unity forums seems to address how to pack scenes into Asset Bundles:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/398630/importing-a-scene-from-assetbundle.html

Good luck

Comment: Indeed it may work on some platforms, however on iOS it would be a problem, as it is not possible to dinamically load new scripts after the app is deployed, not even inside AssetBundles. Of course that, if you don't target iOS, then it may be a very good approach.

Comment: @RafaelSteil unfortunately I don't have experience on the matter on iOS - we only download static content (models, textures, materials) but not scripts, although that sounds very much like Apple's policy :) And my bet is that if their policy is against such a matter, even if you do find a way to do this to bypass it - you won't pass the review process.